# Powershell extend desktop to a display and disable that display on a programmatic toggle?

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, windows-10

wanting to do as the title says. I have a display that I only use occasionally and I'd like to find a faster way of enabling/disabling it. Can someone point me in the right direction, or let me know of a program that can do this? I'm also looking for a way to change the default playback device. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NirSoft have a tool that has command line support, I've not tried it on Windows 10 but it worked fine on Windows 7 when I last used it.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html